# I am trying to create new object from an array of object. I tried using Lodash external library but it crashes the web app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, user-interface, frontend

```
let apiResponse = [{
                   id: 134,
                   user_name: 'abc',
                   phone_number: 1234567890,
                   sno: 'AM'
                },
                {
                  id: 948,
                  user_name: 'def',
                  phone_number: 9823437483,
                  sno: 'AM'
                }, 
                { 
                  id: 865,
                  user_name: 'abc',
                  phone_number: 1234567890,
                  sno: 'PM'                
                },
                {
                  id: 659,
                  user_name: 'ghi',
                  phone_number: 9834763467,
                  sno:'PM'
                },
                {
                  id: 456,
                  user_name: 'ghi',
                  phone_number: 9834763467,
                  sno:'AM'
                },
                {
                  id: 659,
                  user_name: 'ghi',
                  phone_number: 9834763467,
                  sno:'PM'
                }]

Expected Output:
{
    "AM": {
            "134": {
                   id: 134,
                   user_name: 'abc',
                   phone_number: 1234567890,
                   sno: 'AM'
                 }
             "948":{
                  id: 948,
                  user_name: 'def',
                  phone_number: 9823437483,
                  sno: 'AM'
                 }
             "456":{
                  id: 456,
                  user_name: 'ghi',
                  phone_number: 9834763467,
                  sno:'AM'
                 }
            }
      "PM":{
            "865": {
                   id: 865,
                   user_name: 'abc',
                   phone_number: 1234567890,
                   sno: 'PM'
                 }
             "687":{
                  id: 687,
                  user_name: 'def',
                  phone_number: 9823437483,
                  sno: 'PM'
                 }
             "659":{
                  id: 659,
                  user_name: 'ghi',
                  phone_number: 9834763467,
                  sno:'PM'
                 }
           }
         }
}
```

**I am trying to manipulate an array of object into an object. I tried to create expected output by using external library lodash but sometime it crashes the web app. Also tried some other way but didn't get the expected output. Getting problem in creating the nested object. first object key value will be the sno and the key of nested object is id**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group by the wanted properties with nested object.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 134, user_name: 'abc', phone_number: 1234567890, sno: 'AM' }, { id: 948, user_name: 'def', phone_number: 9823437483, sno: 'AM' }, { id: 865, user_name: 'abc', phone_number: 1234567890, sno: 'PM' }, { id: 659, user_name: 'ghi', phone_number: 9834763467, sno:'PM' }, { id: 456, user_name: 'ghi', phone_number: 9834763467, sno:'AM' }, { id: 659, user_name: 'ghi', phone_number: 9834763467, sno:'PM' }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        (r[o.sno] ??= {})[o.id] = o;
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Great! but I question I know about ?? (Nullish Coalescing) but what ??= represents?

Comment: it's the [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment).

Comment: one more thing, what will be the logic if we had object of object instead array of objects?

Comment: then you need to iterate the entries or values of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without using Lodash using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

- First initializes an empty object `({})` as the accumulator `(acc)` for the `reduce` method.
- For each object in the array (curr), it checks whether an object with the current `sno` value exists in the accumulator `(acc[curr.sno])`. If not, it creates an empty object for that `sno` value. Then, it adds the current object to that `sno` object using the id as the key.
- **Finally**, it returns the updated accumulator object.

The reduce method returns the final accumulator object as the output:

```js
let apiResponse = [{ id: 134, user_name: 'abc', phone_number: 1234567890, sno: 'AM' }, { id: 948, user_name: 'def', phone_number: 9823437483, sno: 'AM' }, { id: 865, user_name: 'abc', phone_number: 1234567890, sno: 'PM' }, { id: 659, user_name: 'ghi',
phone_number: 9834763467, sno:'PM' }, { id: 456, user_name: 'ghi', phone_number: 9834763467, sno:'AM' }, { id: 659, user_name: 'ghi', phone_number: 9834763467, sno:'PM' }];
let output = apiResponse.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (!acc[curr.sno]) {
    acc[curr.sno] = {};
  }
  acc[curr.sno][curr.id] = curr;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```